What does a 'chok' type mitzvah mean?

Not rationally comprehensible at all, even to the Divine intellect (an exclusive function of the Divine Will)
Rationally comprehensible by the Divine intellect, but not by humans (supra-rational)
Rationally comprehensible by human intellect but may take hundreds or perhaps thousands of years to arrive at a correct understanding (akin to scientific progress)
Rationally comprehensible in its historical setting but the reason now eludes us


These are not necessarily mutually exclusive. The Lubavitcher Rebbe teaches that all mitzvot are 1, ultimately, even if some have comprehesible reasons attached and some don't. See the machklokes in megilla 25a about if mitzvot are for benefit, or decrees of the king

According to the Rambam, all of the commandments, including the chukkim, have reasons, although we may be ignorant of the reasons. The Rambam says this is the opinion of all Jews (More Nevuchim 3:26; this is also presupposed by every author who wrote a work of the taamei hamitzvot genre). So, although it may be the case that the reason for a chok is unknown, it isn't the defining characteristic of a chok, which should be comprehensible to humans (as the Rambam notes there and 3:31, the value of the chukkim is said to be apparent even to the non-Jews, and Shlomo was supposed to have understood the reasons for all the commandments except for the red cow).
The difference between chukkim and mishpatim is that mishpatim are commandments that we would know to follow even without the Torah, while chukkim are commandments we know to follow only because of the Torah's commandment (Shmona Prakim 6). Or, the chukkim are commandments for which the reason isn't apparent to common people, although it may be known to others (More Nevuchim 3:26).
Another definition is that mishpatim are commandments towards equals, i.e. other humans, and chukkim are commandments towards subordinates, such as animals, plants and self (Rabbi Samson Raphael Hirsch, Nineteen Letters 10).
